# Index contraction with metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

With a metric, it is possible to contract the indices of a tensor as following:

$$
g_{\mu\nu}t^{\mu}_A t^{\nu}_B=t_A t_B
$$
Is it possible to contract then as following
$$
g_{\mu\nu},_\lambda t^{\mu}_A t^{\nu}_B t^{\lambda}_C=t_A t_B t_C
$$
where $g_{\mu\nu},_\lambda=\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^{\lambda}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equation is a bit of an abuse of notation (although it is sometimes used). A better expression would be $$t_A\cdot t_B$$ if it is clear that $t_A, t_B$ are vectors or $$(t_A)^\mu (t_B)_\mu$$ using Einstein's summation convention (as you already did). In the same vein your second equation is an abuse of notation. However, there it is even worse since it appears to be inconsistent with your first definition of $t_At_B$. The expression $t_At_Bt_C$ seems to imply that you can first compute $t_At_B$ and then ''multiply'' this with $t_C$ (or the other way around), but this is not possible since $t_At_B$ has no free indices by your first equation. So I would in general refrain from using such a notation.

However if you make it clear that at every occasion where such a ''triple product'' occurs this specific contraction is implied and if confusion is not possible (or at least improbable) then it is not wrong to use it.

Comment: Yes, the dot is missed$$
g_{\mu\nu},_\lambda t^{\mu}_A t^{\nu}_B t^{\lambda}_C=t_A t_B \cdot t_C
$$ I guess it is a notation as you said. Thank you!

Comment: Again, this is a bit of a weird notation since $t_At_B$ is a scalar by your first definition and $t_C$ a vector. So now you are dotting (whatever it means) into a vector (without explicit indices). This would be (very) confusing to the reader.